# initial degenerations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry, toric-varieties

I am trying to understand the article "Realization spaces for tropical fans" https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4582.pdf by Eric Katz and Sam Payne.

Let $X\subset T$ be a subvariety of the torus.
The topicalization Trop$(X)$ with respect to the trivial valuation is the set $v\in N_\mathbb{R}$ such that the initial degeneration in$_v(X)$ in $T$ is nonempty.

Can someone explain how the initial degeneration is defined in this case or do someone has a good source?

Answer (score 0):

See "Introduction to tropical geometry" by Maclagan and Sturmfels, e.g., Chapter 2.6 or 3.1-2 These initial degeneration $\mathrm{in}_vX$ are exactly the affine schemes whose ideal in $T$ is $\mathrm{in}_vI$ where $I$ is the ideal of $X$ (here, $K$ has the trivial valuation). Since $\mathrm{in}_vX$ is empty if and only if $\mathrm{in}_vI = \langle 1 \rangle$, this statement from Katz and Payne is part of the Fundamental Theorem of Tropical Geometry in Theorem 3.2.3 of this book.